# Is there a way to make os.killpg not kill the script that calls it?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a subprocess which I open, which calls other processes.

I use `os.killpg(os.getpgid(subOut.pid), signal.SIGTERM)` to kill the entire group, but this kills the python script as well. Even when I call a python script with `os.killpg` from a second python script, this kills the second script as well. Is there a way to make `os.killpg`  not stop the script?

Another solution would be to individually kill every child 1process. However, even using

```
p = psutil.Process(subOut.pid)
child_pid = p.children(recursive=True)
for pid in child_pid:
    os.kill(pid.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

does not correctly give me all the pids of the children.

And you know what they say... don't kill the script that calls you...

Comment: When you create a subprocess with `subprocess.Popen` it has an attribute `pid`, I would use that.

Comment: I need to kill a whole group of processes. My subprocess has child processes.

Comment: Can you change the source of the called process? It could call setpgid(mypid, mypid) to make itself a group leader. Your parent process would call os.killpg(childpid).

Comment: As in call setpgid on the original subprocess I called?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to answer, but since google took me here while looking for a related problem: the reason your script gets killed is because its children will, by default, inherit its group id. But you can tell `subprocess.Popen` to create a new process group for your subprocess. Though it's a bit tricky: you have to pass in `os.setpgrp` for the `preexec_fn` parameter. This will call setpgrp (without any arguments) in the newly created (forked) process (before that does the exec) which will set the `gid` of the new process to the `pid` of the new process (thus creating a new group). The documentation mentions that it can deadlock in multi-threaded code. As an alternative, you can use `start_new_session=True`, but that would create not only a new process group but a new session. (And that would mean that if you close your terminal session while your script is running, the children would not be terminated. It may or may not be a problem.)

As a side note, if you are on windows, you can simply pass `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` in the `creationflag` parameter.

Here is what it looks like in detail:

```
subOut = subprocess.Popen(['your', 'subprocess', ...], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

# when it's time to kill
os.killpg(os.getpgid(subOut.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: The original version of the answer referred to the `os.setgrp` function (which doesn't exist) instead of the correct `os.setpgrp`. Thanks to @mowiat for pointing out.

Comment: this really saves me a lot of time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a process group having all the immediate children of the called process as follows:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1)
os.setpgrp(p1.pid, 0) #It will create process group with id same as p1.pid
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2)
os.setpgrp(p2.pid, os.getpgid(p1.pid))

pn = subprocess.Popen(cmdn)
os.setpgrp(pn.pid, os.getpgid(p1.pid))

#Kill all the children and their process tree using following command
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p1.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

It will kill whole process tree except its own process.

Answer (score 0):

atleta's answer above worked for me but the preexec_fn argument in the call to Popen should be setpgrp, rather than setgrp:

```
subOut = subprocess.Popen(['your', 'subprocess', ...], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment on atleta's answer because I don't have comment privileges yet.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to set the parent process to ignore the signal before sending it.

```
# Tell this (parent) process to ignore the signal
old_handler = signal.signal(sig, signal.SIG_IGN)

# Send the signal to our process group and
# wait for them all to exit.
os.killpg(os.getpgid(0), sig)
while os.wait() != -1:
   pass

# Restore the handler
signal.signal(sig, old_handler)
```